# JPA 2.1 Foreign Key isn't saving on ManyToOne cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8, jpa-2.1

I have two classes.

```
public class Reservation {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy = "reservation")
    private List<Night> nights;  \\assume getters and setters
}

public class Night {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESERVATION_ID")
    private Reservation reservation;
}
```

My save works like this:

```
Reservation r = new Reservation();
r.getNights().add(new Night()); 
return dao.save(r);
```

This works, as in it saves the Reservation, and it saves the Night. But when I look at the database, the column RESERVATION_ID in the NIGHT table is null.

In previous projects (before upgrading to Java 8 and JPA 2.1), I didn't need to manually set the parent object on the child in order for that association to save. Did something change, or am I doing something wrong?

Edit:

This saves the association correctly, but it didn't used to be necessary.

```
Reservation r = new Reservation();
Night n = new Night();
n.setReservation(r);
r.getNights().add(n);
return dao.save(r);
```

Comment: Thank you for your link, however I don't see how it helps answer my question. It is a bidirectional relationship, as I show in the code.

Comment: it was back to your question `Did something change, or am I doing something wrong?` So the answer is, you are not missing. That's the way it should be implemented. 
However you can make it unidirectional and add/remove them separately. That's your choice (AFAIK).

Comment: Forgive my confusion, but are you saying `r.getNights().add(new Night());` (before the edit) should work to save the association?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Yes you need to set the parent object in the child. You can do it in the Parent class (child's getter method).

Comment: Alright, so after the edit is how it's supposed to be, and before the edit was just some auto-magic that I shouldn't have been relying on. Correct?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question.

Comment: To clarify: I've been doing it wrong. Right?

Comment: right. Was that working in your previous project? Because AFAIK it shouldn't work properly.

Comment: Yes, but that was JPA 1 and Hibernate 3.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Did you want to write up an answer that I can accept so you can get points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JPA example provided in link below, you need to set the parent object in the child. 
You can do it in the Parent class (child's getter method)

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany